# Issue with pdf generation of graph made with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, pdf-generation, r-package

The below image is the pdf output of a graph i generated using ggplot2. It is stuck loading and is unviewable.

[image]

The below code is a function in a package I am working on used to generate the graph.

```
#'Create frequency spectra
#'
#'This function generates a site-frequnecy spectra based on a dataframe of data created
#'from the lof_funct function.
#'
#'@param data df generated from either lof_funct.R or lof_pos.R
#'@param vcf vcf file from which lof_funct.R was ran on
#'@param outfile file path for the output of the graph
#'@return null
#'@export

## -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
funct_graph<-function(data, vcf, outfile){
  #number of columns (individuals)
  maxc<-ncol(vcf)
  #Converting df to double
  L<-(as.numeric(unlist(data[2])))
  print(L)
  print(maxc)
  print(typeof(L))
  freq <- L / (maxc - 8)
  freq = freq[! freq %in% c(0)]
  #bins for data set = b
  b = sqrt(length(freq))
  #rounding up to nearest integer
  b = ceiling(b)
  allele.df<- data.frame(freq)
  pdf(file=outfile, width=6.5, height = 6.5)
  ggplot(allele.df, aes(x=freq)) +
    geom_histogram(bins=b, binwidth = (max(freq)/b), fill="#69b3a2", color="#e9ecef", alpha=0.9, aes(y=stat(count/sum(count)))) +
    ggtitle("Functional-Class LoF Frequency") +
    theme(panel.background=element_rect(fill='transparent', colour='black'), panel.grid = element_line(colour='grey75'), axis.text=element_text(colour='black'), axis.ticks=element_line(colour='black')) + scale_y_continuous(name="Proportion") + xlab("Allele Frequency")

  dev.off()
}
```

Due to the data type of 'data' being a list, I convert it to a double when assigning it to 'L'. I used a small dataset with 'data' first containing the below values.

| gene.list | LoF Count |
| --- | --- |
| AT1G01020 | 345 |
| AT1G01050 | 17 |

'vcf' is a list with 1144 columns

I checked that the conversion of 'data' to a double worked and printed 'L' to check its contents and everything seemed in order.

Additionally, I ran the function as a separate script and got the output desired linked below

[image]

Here is the script for redundancy

```
#number of columns (individuals)
maxc<-ncol(vcf)
#Converting df to double
L<-(as.numeric(unlist(funct[2])))
print(L)
print(maxc)
print(typeof(L))
freq <- L / (maxc - 8)
freq = freq[! freq %in% c(0)]
#bins for data set = b
b = sqrt(length(freq))
#rounding up to nearest integer
b = ceiling(b)
allele.df<- data.frame(freq)
pdf(file="C:/Users/raymu/Downloads/funct.graph.pdf", width=6.5, height = 6.5)
ggplot(allele.df, aes(x=freq)) +
  geom_histogram(bins=b, binwidth = (max(freq)/b), fill="#69b3a2", color="#e9ecef", alpha=0.9, aes(y=stat(count/sum(count)))) +
  ggtitle("Functional-Class LoF Frequency") +
  theme(panel.background=element_rect(fill='transparent', colour='black'), panel.grid = element_line(colour='grey75'), axis.text=element_text(colour='black'), axis.ticks=element_line(colour='black')) + scale_y_continuous(name="Proportion") + xlab("Allele Frequency")

dev.off()
```

Everything is identical between the the two expect the variable 'funct' is used in the script but 'funct' contains the same 'data' and is used when using the the function of the package, applying it to the 'data' parameter. Please let me know if there is any other information that is needed

Comment: When you create a ggplot interactively, its `print` method is invoked (by the usual implicit printing). If you create it inside a function, no implicit printing is going on and the `print` method isn't invoked. You need to wrap your ggplot in `print(...)`. See also: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-do-lattice_002ftrellis-graphics-not-work_003f (ggplot2 uses the same graphics "engine"  as lattice, i.e., the grid package)

Comment: dev.off will shut off the graphics device. try to comment it out in your function and run it again, since R will automatically rturn the last line of your function it only returns dev.off() . if the last line is the call to ggplot it will return the ggplot.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify what the function should return (if you want it to return  something) `@return null` is bad practice and fell on your feet.
See this small example on the return behavior of r functions.

```
## Ex 1:
myplotfun <- function(data) {
  ggplot(data,aes(cyl,mpg,group=cyl))+geom_boxplot()
  "i return the last line by default"
}
myplotfun(mtcars)

## Ex 2:
myplotfun2 <- function(data) {
  "i always return the last line by default"
  ggplot(data,aes(cyl,mpg,group=cyl))+geom_boxplot()
}
myplotfun2(mtcars)

## Ex 3:
myplotfun3 <- function(data) {
  return("....exept you specifiy the return")
  ggplot(data,aes(cyl,mpg,group=cyl))+geom_boxplot()
}
myplotfun3(mtcars)

## Ex 4:
myplotfun4 <- function(data) {
  p<-ggplot(data,aes(cyl,mpg,group=cyl))+geom_boxplot()
  message("maybe you want to do it like this:")
  return(p)
}
myplotfun4(mtcars)



## Ex 5 SAVINg ggplot to pdf:

myplotfun5 <- function(data) {
  ggplot(data,aes(cyl,mpg,group=cyl))+geom_boxplot()
  message("Saving PDF Image..")
  ggsave("~/Documents/rtest/fig.pdf",device = "pdf")
}
myplotfun5(mtcars)
```

Comment: OP is only interested in the side effect of creating the PDF. He doesn't need to return the plot.